# The pronunciation of "s" in nouns and verbs

Tags: pronunciation

What is the suffix mentioned in this  explanation? Is it the "s"? If the "s" in verbs is pronounced as "z" before vowels, for example, "sees", does the same rule apply to nouns? I mean is the "s" pronounced as "z" in plural nouns if it is preceeded by a vowel?

> A: The third person singular suffix of regular verbs
> and
>
> B: The genitive suffix of the singular form of regular nouns
> and
>
> C. The  plural suffix of regular nouns
>
> are pronounced:
>
> /s/ after unvoiced consonants (except /s/, /ʃ/ and /tʃ/ - hits, Pat's, cups
>
> /z/ after voiced consonants (except /z/, /ʒ/ and /dʒ/) and after vowels - hums, Tom's, cans
>
> and
>
> /ɪz/ after /s/, /z/, /ʃ/, /ʒ/ ,/tʃ/,/dʒ/ - washes, Chris's, ditches.

Comment: The suffix is -s or -es (as in _he watches_)

Comment: *If the "s" in verbs is pronounced as "z" before vowels* - don't you mean **after** vowels?

Comment: They are pronounced /s/ or /z/ ***after*** voiced/unvoiced consonants, not "before"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is referring to the three different endings which are all basically *-s*, and all have the same range of pronunciations in the same contexts.

Note that the possessive ending is never written '-es', but still generally has the same change in pronunciation, eg *witches* (plural), *witch's* (singular possessive), and *witches'* (plural possessive) are all pronounced identically.

When you say "before vowels", you mean "after vowels".

Comment: So is "s" pronounced as "z" after vowels in plural nouns in the same way it's pronounced as "z" after vowels in third person singular verbs as in "sees"?

Comment: The list of examples which you quote includes nouns and proper nouns as well as verbs.

Comment: @AntoniaA: yes. _Sees_ (pl. noun, "bishoprics") and _sees_ (3s verb, "perceives visually") are precise homophones.

Comment: I am trying to find more examples. Are there not so many words in which the "s" is pronounced as "z" after vowels in plural. I mean as in your example, "sees" pl noun.

Comment: No, it's completely normal to voice the _-s_ after vowels, irrespective of the grammatical function. _Shows_, _cows_, _buys_, _stays_, _queues_ are all pronounced with /z/ as both nouns and verbs. Note that it's the _sound_ that matters, not the spelling: _dates_ has a vowel _letter_ before the _-s_, but the _sound_ preceding it is /t/, so the _-s_ is pronounced /s/, as both noun and verb.

Comment: Thank you very much!